# CakePHP 3: reusable validator

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have created a reusable validator as described [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#creating-reusable-validators), for example `App\Validation\PageValidator`. Now I cannot understand how to make my table uses the new validator (and not `Cake\Validation\Validator`).

In fact, I see that the method `PagesTable::validationDefault()` still expects an instance of `Cake\Validation\Validator` and not of `App\Validation\PageValidator`.

How can I do? Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You return your reusable validator from `validationDefault`:

```
public function validationDefault($validator)
{
    $validator = new \App\Validation\PageValidator;
    return $validator;
}
```